# AWS @LambdaFunction can't deserialize to POJO

Tags: java, aws-lambda, jackson

I'm using Spring Boot (2.26) with AWS SDK for Java (1.11.761).

My problem is that @LambdaFunction fails to deserialize to my POJO, failing with:

> "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot
>   construct instance of `com.example.Sentence` (although at least one
>   Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to
>   deserialize from String value ('{"end": 16, "id": 1, "start": 0,
>   "text": "Hello, Foobar!!!", "type": "SENTENCE", "uuid":
>   "de0134a93c1f4f2dbd910ae39438359d", "warnings": []}')  at [Source:
>   (byte[])""{\"end\": 16, \"id\": 1, \"start\": 0, \"text\": \"Hello,
>   Foobar!!!\", \"type\": \"SENTENCE\", \"uuid\":
>   \"de0134a93c1f4f2dbd910ae39438359d\", \"warnings\": []}""; line: 1,
>   column: 1]

```
public interface TemplateLambda {
    @LambdaFunction(functionName="....")
    Sentence getSentence(TemplateInput input);

    @LambdaFunction(functionName="....")
    String getString(TemplateInput input);
}

@Data
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Sentence {

    @JsonIgnore
    private UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();

    private Long id;
    private String text;
    private String type;
    private List<Warning> warnings = new ArrayList<>();
    private Long start;
    private Long end;
}
```

Invoked with:

```
final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
            .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

final TemplateLambda lambda = LambdaInvokerFactory.builder()
            .lambdaClient(AWSLambdaClientBuilder.defaultClient())
            .objectMapper(objectMapper)
            .build(TemplateLambda.class);

TemplateInput input = new TemplateInput("Foobar");
try {
    String s = lambda.getString(input);
    Sentence sent = objectMapper.readValue(s, Sentence.class); // SUCCEEDS
    logger.info("THIS SUCCEEDS);

    Sentence output = lambda.getSentence(input); // FAILS
    logger.info("THIS FAILS");

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I've also verified that skipping the @LambdaFunction annotation and manually invoking gives an escaped JSON string in byte[] format, ie '\"{\"id\":\123}\"'.  If I don't manually unescape this and remove the leading and trailing quotes, I get the same failure.

It appears that if I ask for String as return type, the SDK will deal with unescaping it, but if I ask for POJO, it just hands the escaped byte[] to Jackson and Jackson fails.

As there any configuration I can do on Jackson or the SDK to prevent this?  I've already tried excluding Jackson from Maven dependencies of AWS SDk in case I was getting conflicting versions, but got same result.

Comment: can you provide the code of your Sentence class? I believe the problem is in there

Comment: Thanks, I added the Sentence class.  You'll note that uuid is @JSONIgnored, this is an annoyance about UUID that I need to fix - but the class deserializes fine when I am doing it myself using objectMapper.readValue(s, Sentence.class) when ignoring uuid.

Answer (score 0):

You need a way for jackson to construct your Sentence object. There are two ways to accomplish this:

1. add an empty constructor and getter and setter methods, maybe you would need `@JsonProperty("fieldName")` on each field (except for uuid)
2. add a constructor with `@JsonCreator` on it and `@JsonProperty("filedName")` for each argument of the constructor, I would add getter method too

```
@JsonCreator
public Sentence(@JsonProperty("id")Long id,
     @JsonProperty("text")String text,
     @JsonProperty("type") String type,
     @JsonProperty("warnings") List<Warning> warnings,
     @JsonProperty("start") Long start,
     @JsonProperty("end") Long end) {
    this.id = id;
    this.text = text;
    this.type = type;
    this.warnings = new ArrayList<>();
    this.start = start;
    this.end = end;
}
```

In my preference the second method is better in order to use immutable objects